# Losing rep when a Q is removed

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

this post: '[How to Solve It: Add Your Heuristics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134418/how-to-solve-it-add-your-heuristics)' has been removed. I had an answer on it which made me 20rep, which I have now lost. But it wasn't my question, so why has my rep been lost?

Comment: Does [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/19338/11619) fit? A quick summary: answering a badly formulated question runs the risk of not keeping any of the eventual rep points, if the question is later deleted. So it is *status-by-design*. In many cases you can take rescue action by editing the question so that it meets our quality standards. I'm not sure that this is feasible in the case of such an open-ended question. If you think the question was unjustly deleted you can plead the case [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/19042/11619).

Comment: not really, I was awarded the rep in good faith, my answers were accepted, so why should I suffer?

Comment: if I'd lost rep would I have got it back?

Comment: A) "Vox Populi" said that the question was not welcome on our site, so no reputation should have come from it in the first place. B) Yes. If your answer had received downvotes, and you had lost rep points, those points would have been restored to you when the answer is removed. Irrespective of how the removal happened. You can always cut the losses resulting from downvotes by deleting the answer yourself. If the answer has gotten both upvotes and downvotes, then you have to do a bit of arithmetic :-)

Comment: but i've stuck that rep in the bank, and now i haven't got it

Comment: This is just how the site works. Looks like the bank formed by this question went belly up.

Comment: @Jyrki: The banking crisis does not skip MSE. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately not. Jon can ask for the taxpayers to foot the bill in the Reopen/... Request thread (see the right margin or my earlier comment for the link), but they may not go for it.

Comment: @Jyrki: One quote comes to mind, "*I'm gonna take you to the bank, Senator Trent. To the blood bank!*"

Comment: +1 for stating this question. I always wondered what would happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was your answer, and the answer was deleted along with the question.

Comment: does downvoting this answer cost me rep?

Comment: No, voting on meta has no effect on reputation.

Comment: it does on meta meta

Comment: Meta.SE is not linked to a specific site, it is its own site, so of course it works like that there.